# Connections could not be acquired from th e underlying database! -- HSQL DB

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hsqldb

I am trying to learn Hibernate from Java Persistence with hibernate by Gavin King.

I just downloaded the examples given in the book from this location http://downloads.jboss.org/hibernate/caveatemptor/jpwh-gettingstarted-070401.zip

I started my HSQL db using ant startdb and database started successfully.

When trying to run the target schemaexport I am getting the below error..

> schemaexport: [hibernatetool]
>   Executing Hibernate Tool with a
>   Standard Configuration [hibernatetool]
>   1. task: hbm2ddl (Generates database schema) [hibernatetool] 18:07:56,555 
>   INFO Environment:500 - Hibernate
>   3.2.0.cr5 [hibernatetool] 18:07:56,555  INFO Environment:533 -
>   hibernate.properties not fo und
>   [hibernatetool] 18:07:56,555  INFO
>   Environment:667 - Bytecode provider
>   name : cg lib [hibernatetool]
>   18:07:56,571  INFO Environment:584 -
>   using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Time stamp
>   handling [hibernatetool] 18:07:56,617 
>   INFO Configuration:1384 - configuring
>   from file: h ibernate.cfg.xml
>   [hibernatetool] 18:07:56,680  INFO
>   Configuration:507 - Reading mappings
>   from res ource: hello/Message.hbm.xml
>   [hibernatetool] 18:07:56,758  INFO
>   HbmBinder:300 - Mapping class:
>   hello.Message
>   -> MESSAGES [hibernatetool] 18:07:56,851  INFO Configuration:1465
>   - Configured SessionFactor y: null [hibernatetool] 18:07:56,851  INFO
>   Dialect:141 - Using dialect:
>   org.hibernate.di alect.HSQLDialect
>   [hibernatetool] 18:07:56,914  INFO
>   SchemaExport:154 - Running hbm2ddl
>   schema exp ort [hibernatetool]
>   18:07:56,914  INFO SchemaExport:174 -
>   writing generated schema t o file:
>   C:\Users\Ramesh\Desktop\Tutorials\hibernate\Hibernate
>   Code samples\jpwh-
>   gettingstarted-070401\helloworld-native\helloworld-ddl.sql
>   [hibernatetool] 18:07:56,914  INFO
>   SchemaExport:179 - exporting generated
>   schema  to database [hibernatetool]
>   18:07:56,914  INFO
>   C3P0ConnectionProvider:50 - C3P0 using
>   driver : org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver at URL:
>   jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost
>   [hibernatetool] 18:07:56,914  INFO
>   C3P0ConnectionProvider:51 - Connection
>   proper ties: {user=sa} [hibernatetool]
>   18:07:56,914  INFO
>   C3P0ConnectionProvider:54 - autocommit
>   mode: false [hibernatetool]
>   18:08:26,554  WARN
>   BasicResourcePool:1222 -
>   com.mchange.v2.resou
>   rcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@61f1680f
>   -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While
>   trying to acquire a needed new
>   resource, we fai led to succeed more
>   than the maximum number of allowed
>   acquisition attempts (30) .
>   [hibernatetool] 18:08:26,554 ERROR
>   SchemaExport:202 - schema export
>   unsuccessful
>
> [hibernatetool] java.sql.SQLException:
>   Connections could not be acquired from
>   th e underlying database!
>   [hibernatetool]         at
>   com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.j
>   ava:104) [hibernatetool]         at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.che
>   ckoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:236)
>   [hibernatetool]         at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource.getConnectio
>   n(PoolBackedDataSource.java:94)
>   [hibernatetool]         at
>   org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getCo
>   nnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:35)
>   [hibernatetool]         at
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.ManagedProviderConnectionH
>   elper.prepare(ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.java:28)
>   [hibernatetool]         at
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(Schem
>   aExport.java:180) [hibernatetool]
>   at
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(Schema
>   Export.java:133) [hibernatetool]
>   at
>   org.hibernate.tool.ant.Hbm2DDLExporterTask.execute(Hb
>   m2DDLExporterTask.java:55)
>   [hibernatetool]         at
>   org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask.execute(Hibe
>   rnateToolTask.java:171)
>   [hibernatetool]         at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownEl
>   ement.java:291) [hibernatetool]
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   M ethod) [hibernatetool]         at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMet
>   hodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   [hibernatetool]         at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Deleg
>   atingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   [hibernatetool]         at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   [hibernatetool]         at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(D
>   ispatchUtils.java:106) [hibernatetool]
>   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>   [hibernatetool]         at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
>   [hibernatetool]         at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:
>   411) [hibernatetool]         at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Pro
>   ject.java:1397) [hibernatetool]
>   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.ja
>   va:1366) [hibernatetool]         at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTa
>   rgets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>   [hibernatetool]         at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.j
>   ava:1249) [hibernatetool]         at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:801)
>   [hibernatetool]         at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:218)
>   [hibernatetool]         at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.jav
>   a:280) [hibernatetool]         at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.ja
>   va:109) [hibernatetool] Caused by:
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceExce
>   ption: A ResourcePool could not
>   acquire a resource from its primary
>   factory or s ource. [hibernatetool]
>   at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAc
>   quire(BasicResourcePool.java:970)
>   [hibernatetool]         at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkou
>   tResource(BasicResourcePool.java:208)
>   [hibernatetool]         at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.che
>   ckoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:232)
>   [hibernatetool]         ... 24 more
>   [hibernatetool] 1 errors occurred
>   while performing .
>   [hibernatetool] Error #1:
>   java.sql.SQLException: Connections
>   could not be acquir ed from the
>   underlying database! [hibernatetool]
>   18:08:26,569  WARN
>   BasicResourcePool:1222 -
>   com.mchange.v2.resou
>   rcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@72f864fe
>   -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While
>   trying to acquire a needed new
>   resource, we fai led to succeed more
>   than the maximum number of allowed
>   acquisition attempts (30) .`

I don't have too much knowledge about either hiberate or HSQL..

Some one please explain whats wrong here??

Thanks

**EDIT:** I am trying to run the project `helloworld-native`.

The target given in the ant build.xml for startdb is as below:

```
<!-- Start the HSQL DB server -->
<target name="startdb" description="Run HSQL database server with clean DB">
    <!-- Delete database files -->
    <delete dir="${database.dir}"/>
    <java classname="org.hsqldb.Server"
          fork="yes"
          classpathref="project.classpath"
          failonerror="true">
        <arg value="-database.0"/>
        <arg value="file:${database.dir}/db"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

and when i run the command `ant startdb` i see the below output:

```
startdb:
     [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\Ramesh\Desktop\Tutorials\hibernate\Hibernate Code samples\jpwh-gettingstarted-070401\helloworld-native\database
     [java] [Server@15ded0fd]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) entered
     [java] [Server@15ded0fd]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) exited

     [java] [Server@15ded0fd]: Startup sequence initiated from main() method
     [java] [Server@15ded0fd]: Loaded properties from [C:\Users\Ramesh\Desktop\Tutorials hibernate\Hibernate Code samples\jpwh-gettingstarted-070401\helloworld-native\server.properties]
     [java] [Server@15ded0fd]: Initiating startup sequence...
     [java] [Server@15ded0fd]: Server socket opened successfully in 29 ms.
     [java] [Server@15ded0fd]: Database [index=0, id=0, db=file:database/db, alias=] opened sucessfully in 469 ms.
     [java] [Server@15ded0fd]: Startup sequence completed in 523 ms.
     [java] [Server@15ded0fd]: 2010-11-08 22:11:08.027 HSQLDB server 1.8.0 is online
     [java] [Server@15ded0fd]: To close normally, connect and execute SHUTDOWN SQL
     [java] [Server@15ded0fd]: From command line, use [Ctrl]+[C] to abort abruptly
```

Then, i think i am running HSQL DB in server mode only (from the above output)..

Please tell me what else I am missing..

Comment: Tried with mysql..and it is working..Dont know what the probelm is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** After a second look, it appears that I was wrong, you can start HSQL in server mode using the ant script and you're not forced to use the command line. Actually, I tried to reproduce the problem with the `helloworld-native` sample but it worked fine for me.

First, I started HSQLDB in a first shell using `ant startdb`:

```
$ ant startdb 
Buildfile: /home/pascal/Projects/jpwh-gettingstarted-070401/helloworld-native/build.xml

startdb:
     [java] [Server@a97b0b]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) entered
     [java] [Server@a97b0b]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) exited
     [java] [Server@a97b0b]: Startup sequence initiated from main() method
     [java] [Server@a97b0b]: Loaded properties from [/home/pascal/Projects/jpwh-gettingstarted-070401/helloworld-native/server.properties]
     [java] [Server@a97b0b]: Initiating startup sequence...
     [java] [Server@a97b0b]: Server socket opened successfully in 39 ms.
     [java] [Server@a97b0b]: Database [index=0, id=0, db=file:database/db, alias=] opened sucessfully in 1148 ms.
     [java] [Server@a97b0b]: Startup sequence completed in 1281 ms.
     [java] [Server@a97b0b]: 2010-11-08 18:29:20.094 HSQLDB server 1.8.0 is online
     [java] [Server@a97b0b]: To close normally, connect and execute SHUTDOWN SQL
     [java] [Server@a97b0b]: From command line, use [Ctrl]+[C] to abort abruptly
```

Then, I ran `ant schemaexport` from another shell:

```
$ ant schemaexport 
Buildfile: /home/pascal/Projects/jpwh-gettingstarted-070401/helloworld-native/build.xml

compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/pascal/Projects/jpwh-gettingstarted-070401/helloworld-native/build
    [javac] /home/pascal/Projects/jpwh-gettingstarted-070401/helloworld-native/build.xml:39: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to /home/pascal/Projects/jpwh-gettingstarted-070401/helloworld-native/build

copymetafiles:
     [copy] Copying 3 files to /home/pascal/Projects/jpwh-gettingstarted-070401/helloworld-native/build

schemaexport:
[hibernatetool] Executing Hibernate Tool with a Standard Configuration
[hibernatetool] 1. task: hbm2ddl (Generates database schema)
[hibernatetool] 
[hibernatetool]     alter table MESSAGES 
[hibernatetool]         drop constraint FK_NEXT_MESSAGE;
[hibernatetool] 
[hibernatetool]     drop table MESSAGES if exists;
[hibernatetool] 
[hibernatetool]     create table MESSAGES (
[hibernatetool]         MESSAGE_ID bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1),
[hibernatetool]         MESSAGE_TEXT varchar(255),
[hibernatetool]         NEXT_MESSAGE_ID bigint,
[hibernatetool]         primary key (MESSAGE_ID)
[hibernatetool]     );
[hibernatetool] 
[hibernatetool]     alter table MESSAGES 
[hibernatetool]         add constraint FK_NEXT_MESSAGE 
[hibernatetool]         foreign key (NEXT_MESSAGE_ID) 
[hibernatetool]         references MESSAGES;
[hibernatetool] 1 errors occurred while performing <hbm2ddl>.
[hibernatetool] Error #1: java.sql.SQLException: Table not found: MESSAGES in statement [alter table MESSAGES]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 14 seconds
```

And indeed, when running `ant dbmanager`, I can see the `MESSAGES` table as expected.

So everything worked just fine, out of the box. If it doesn't for you, maybe start looking at things such as a networking issue, a personal firewall, etc.

---

According to the trace, it looks like HSQL is not started (at least not in server mode) and I suspect that you didn't start it like you are supposed to. To start it in server mode, from the `helloworld-reverse` directory, run (as explained in the section *Starting the HSQL database system*, p 98):

```
$ java -cp lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.Server
```

Then you'll be able to connect to it using the `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost` connection string.

Comment: Pascal, I added comments to the question...You can look at when you have time..Thanks in advance..

Comment: Thanks Pascal..making time to look at my question...As you said i think the problem might be with the network..However, I am able to proceed with `MySql` DB. Thanks again